# SQL Query only displaying first result rather than arrayed data

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am building a calendar page that displays the months, and the days of the month(pulled from my database) and then any days that are inside the "start_date - end_date" variables are displayed with a different cell background color to the days that don't have a start or end date assigned, I have it working to an extent but it's only displaying the earliest of each months record rather than all the results.

ie.

```
    2015-03-12(start) - 2015-03-16(end)
    2015-03-03(start) - 2015-03-10(end)
```

And rather than display like this...

```
`1 2 [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] 11 [12 13 14 15 16] 17 18 19 20 ...`
```

it's just showing the `[3 - 10]` record, here is my current code..

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0">
 <?php
 $cmonth = date('F'); 
 $cyear = date('Y');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE year = '$cyear' ORDER BY m_order ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$month_end = $rows['days_in_month'];
$month_name = $rows['month_name'];
$m_order = $rows['m_order'];

 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM trips WHERE start_date LIKE '____-0$m_order-__'      ORDER BY start_date ASC";
 $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);

 $stdate = $row['start_date'];
 $s = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $stdate);

 $endate = $row['end_date'];
 $e = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $endate);

 $start = $s['day'];
 $end = $e['day'];

 ?>
 <tr>
 <td width="80px"><?php echo $month_name; ?></td>
 <?php

 foreach(range(1, $month_end) as $days) 
 {
 if(in_array($days, range($start, $end)))
 {
 echo "<td style=\"background-color: #ccc;\" align=\"center\">" . $days .    "    </td>";
 }
 else
 echo "<td align=\"center\">" . $days . "</td>";
 }
 ?>
 </tr>

 <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

Also I am aware of the dangers not using mysqli but I am just learning this on my local machine and plan on researching updated strategies once I get the functions working, so I'll know if my functions are broken or my coding is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with common function to read data from table

```
 function db_set_recordset($sql) {
        $qry = mysql_query($sql);
        $row= array();
        while($out = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {

                $row[] = $out;

        }
        return $row;
} 
 $cmonth = date('F'); 
 $cyear = date('Y');

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE year = '$cyear' ORDER BY m_order ASC";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$month_end = $rows['days_in_month'];
$month_name = $rows['month_name'];
$m_order = $rows['m_order'];

 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM trips WHERE start_date LIKE '____-0$m_order-__'      ORDER BY start_date ASC";
 $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
 $row = db_set_recordset($res2);

 $stdate = $row['start_date'];
 $s = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $stdate);

 $endate = $row['end_date'];
 $e = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $endate);

 $start = $s['day'];
 $end = $e['day'];

 ?>
 <tr>
 <td width="80px"><?php echo $month_name; ?></td>
 <?php

 foreach(range(1, $month_end) as $days) 
 {
 if(in_array($days, range($start, $end)))
 {
 echo "<td style=\"background-color: #ccc;\" align=\"center\">" . $days .    "    </td>";
 }
 else
 echo "<td align=\"center\">" . $days . "</td>";
 }
 ?>
 </tr>

 <?php } ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it has fixed the display issue with the months, but it is no longer displaying the ""<td style=\"background-color: #ccc;\" align=\"center\">"" for the dates in the array of start - end.

Answer (score 0):

You are only fetching one row of your result set from your `trips` table.  You need something like this to get the second one.

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2) ) {
    /* process each row */
}
```

You're doing this right for your other result set.  Take a look at the examples here:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

You'll need to run through the result set rows and accumulate your "hot" days, then render the days just once.  Something like this:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM trips WHERE start_date LIKE '____-0$m_order-__'      ORDER BY start_date ASC";
 $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
    $stdate = $row['start_date'];
    $s = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $stdate);

    $endate = $row['end_date'];
    $e = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $endate);

    $start = $s['day'];
    $end = $e['day'];
    $hot_days = array();
    foreach(range(1, $month_end) as $days)  {
        $hot_days[$days] = 0;
        if(in_array($days, range($start, $end))) {
            $hot_days[$days] ++;
        }
    }
}
/* now you have a $hot_days array with nonzero values for interesting days */
?>
<tr>
  <td width="80px"><?php echo $month_name; ?></td>
   <?php
      foreach(range(1, $month_end) as $day)  {
          if($hot_days[$day] > 0) {
              echo "<td style=\"background-color: #ccc;\" align=\"center\">" . $days .    "    </td>";
          } 
          else {
              echo "<td align=\"center\">" . $days . "</td>";
          }
      }
     ?>
     </tr>
```

With respect, I don't have time to debug this.

Comment: Thank you I have just made that change but now rather than display 2 sets of dates on the same month, it's displaying the month twice..

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2zzrc03.jpg